# Rendering component in React shows flicker

Tags: reactjs, rendering

Can anyone explain to me the main difference between rendering a JSX Component as a function and as a Tag. The achieved result is the same but somehow if I render JSX component like `<Display/>` show a flicker on the screen but rendering the component like `{Display()}` work absolutely fine. For both the cases, the component is re-render.

Note: I am navigating between the page and every time I navigate back to the screens, I'm re-rendering it intentionally to update the previous screen.

```
const App = ()=> {
  const Display = ()=>{
   console.log(" === Rendering display ===")
   return (
     <h1> Hello there.. </h1>
   )

  return(
  <div>
    <Display/>
    {Display()}
  </div>

}
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is happening is that you are defining your component `Display` from within another component (in this case `App`).

This is an anti-pattern, as the component will be redefined on every render of its parent component.

The correct way would be to define these components separately:

```
const Display = ()=> {
 console.log(" === Rendering display ===")
 return (
   <h1> Hello there.. </h1>
 );
}

const App = () => {
  return(
  <div>
    <Display/>
    {Display()}
  </div>
  )
}
```

As to the difference between both methods, here is a summary taken from [an article posted by Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) on the subject:

> React doesn't know the difference between us calling a function in our JSX and inlining it. So it cannot associate anything to the Counter function, because it's not being rendered like a component.